# exchange powershell list sendas, send on behalf of, AND fullaccess for a given mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

For a given mailbox, I want to list of any users who have *any* of the following permissions:

- send as
- send on behalf of
- full access

I haven't been able to find a simple way to get all 3 at once, so I have been going at it on a per permission basis...

```
get-exolmailbox -identity "example@example.com" | get-exolmailboxpermission | where { ($_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") }

get-exolmailbox -Identity "example@example.com" | Get-ADPermission | ? { ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send*") -or ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*full*") -and -not ($_.User -like "*\self*") } | FT -auto User,ExtendedRights

get-exolmailbox -identity "example@example.com" | fl displayname, grantsendonbehalfto
```

Is there was a more elegant way to get that same info before I put some time into figuring out how to format the results the way I want?

I would prefer to end up with an excel file that lists each user by display name and which permissions they have to the mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want, it creates a custom object and assigns the info from your commands to its properties.

```
$emailaddress = "user1@example.com","user2@example.com"

$MailboxPermissions = @()

foreach ($email in $emailaddress)
{
    $exolmailbox = get-exolmailbox -identity $email

    $FullAccess = $exolmailbox | where { ($_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") }
    $SendAs = $exolmailbox | Get-ADPermission | ? { ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*send*") -or ($_.ExtendedRights -like "*full*") -and -not ($_.User -like "*\self*") }

    $MailboxInfo = New-Object System.Object

    $MailboxInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DisplayName -value $exolmailbox.displayname
    $MailboxInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FullAccess -value $FullAccess
    $MailboxInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SendAsUser -value $SendAs.User
    $MailboxInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SendAsExtendedRights -value $SendAs.ExtendedRights
    $MailboxInfo | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name GrantSendOnBehalfTo -value $exolmailbox.grantsendonbehalfto

    $MailboxPermissions += $MailboxInfo
}

$MailboxPermissions
```

Note: I can't test this as I can't find anything online that references `get-exolmailbox`, and I've only ever seen/used `get-mailbox` before.

Comment: I should have mentioned that earlier sorry.  My powershell session is connected to both the on-prem exchange server and the exchange online environment. the "exol" part is a just a prefix you can assign so the system knows to which environment you are issuing the commands.  we went with exol as short for exchange online...